# Access Drools Guvnor from OSGI bundle

Tags: java, osgi, drools, guvnor

I am using following code to access Drools Guvnor:

```
KnowledgeAgentConfiguration kaconf = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgentConfiguration();
KnowledgeAgent kagent = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgent("MyAgent", kaconf);
kagent.applyChangeSet(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("drools/change-set.xml"));
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kagent.getKnowledgeBase().newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
```

Unfortunately `KnowledgeAgentFactory` class does not seem to be OSGI ready as it uses `Class.forName()` to load agent provider. `KnowledgeAgentFactory` resides in knowledge-api bundle, and provider implementation in drools-core bundle. Obviously knowledge-api doesn't see drools-core in OSGI container. As a result I get following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentProviderImpl could not be set.
    at org.drools.agent.KnowledgeAgentFactory.loadProvider(KnowledgeAgentFactory.java:191)[162:org.drools.api:5.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.agent.KnowledgeAgentFactory.getKnowledgeAgentProvider(KnowledgeAgentFactory.java:178)[162:org.drools.api:5.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.agent.KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgentConfiguration(KnowledgeAgentFactory.java:129)[162:org.drools.api:5.5.0.Final]
```

Is there workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might help yourself with a require-bundle manifest entry since it doesn't seem to work correctly with those imports and I'd say at that point it's probably the best to get it working that way.

[Require-Bundle](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Require-Bundle) as defined in the osgi wiki

Comment: Both Require-Bundle and Import-Bundle does seem to help here